# Which formulas support characters like the "&" "|" " * "

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

How would I check which formulas support characters like &,|, and *?

This source lists all but "&" as REGEX characters.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en&ref_topic=1034375

Does this mean that they are only usable in REGEX formulas? (R.-MATCH -EXTRACT -REPLACE) and QUERY?
Is the & sign only applicable then, in patching text together like this - A1&"whatever" -?

I could not find a definitive source for this topic, can you help me out? :)

(I'm asking because this is clearly not working while being the more clear solution:
IF(A1=1 | 2, TRUE) and needs to be done redundantly like this
IFS(A1=1; TRUE; A1=2; TRUE)
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pipe `|` is a product of regex language mimicking `OR` function and can be used in

```
REGEXMATCH
REGEXEXTRACT
REGEXREPLACE
IMPORTXML
QUERY (only in conjunction with "matches")
```

asterisk `*` is a wildcard character that can be used in the above-mentioned functions and even further within

```
COUNTIF
COUNTIFS
MATCH
VLOOKUP
```

character `&` is common across various functions used mainly instead:

```
CONCAT
CONCATENATION
```

coz it's short and joins stuff nicely.

then there is `ARRAYFORMULA` which does not support functions like

```
AND
OR
```

so we use `*` multiplication for `AND` and `+` sign instead of `OR`

so your `IF(A1=1 | 2, TRUE)` should be:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1&"", "1|2")
=OR(A1=1, A1=2)
```

and for arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(A1&"", "1|2"))
=ARRAYFORMULA((A1=1)+(A1=2))
```

Comment: Of course, the OR function returns BOOLEAN on its own ... I wasn't aware at the moment. 
Thank you very much for the explanations, most appreciated :-)

Comment: \* A better translation of `IF(A1=1 | 2, TRUE)` into regex is `=REGEXMATCH(A1&"","^(1|2)$")` as `=REGEXMATCH(A1&"", "1|2")` will return TRUE also if A1 *contains* 1 or 2 but it's not equal to them. I would also add that the **asterisk (\*)** is generally accepted by all the `...IF()/IFS()` functions such as `SUMIF/S(), AVERAGEIF/S(), MINIFS()` etc...